# Print absolute slot number

Tags: c, contiki

I want to print the `Absolute slot number` inside the `tsch_calculate_channel`function.

The ASN is defined as:

```
/* The ASN is an absolute slot number over 5 bytes. */
struct tsch_asn_t {
  uint32_t ls4b; /* least significant 4 bytes */
  uint8_t  ms1b; /* most significant 1 byte */
};
```

I tried it with:

```
/* Channel hopping utility functions */
/* Return channel from ASN and channel offset */
uint8_t
tsch_calculate_channel(struct tsch_asn_t *asn, uint8_t channel_offset)
{
  int value =  (asn->ms1b << 8) | asn->ls4b ;
  printf("%d \n\n", value);
 uint16_t index_of_0 = TSCH_ASN_MOD(*asn, tsch_hopping_sequence_length);
 uint16_t index_of_offset = (index_of_0 + channel_offset) % tsch_hopping_sequence_length.val;
 return tsch_hopping_sequence[index_of_offset];
}
```

Which prints: 48041, 48048, 48055, 48062, 48069....

How can i combine/merge those to bytes to print the correct ASN?.

Comment: What output did you expect instead?

Comment: consecutive decimal number: 1022, 1023, 1024 ....

Comment: Apparently the value of `asn` is not what you expected it to be. You need to debug the other code. I suspect the problem is that you expect the  tsch_calculate_channel function to be called once every slot, while in fact it is called once every active slot in Contiki-NG. By default, one slot in seven is active.